# What is versioning (as in GitVersion) used for?

Tags: versioning

http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/why/ and https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion explain the advantage of   GitVersion over "Version.txt/Version in build script" and "Build Server versioning"

Before being able to understand the differences between the three approaches, what kind of problem do the three try to solve in common? In other words, what is versioning used for in the context of the three approaches?

Isn't a new version number created, by simply incrementing the version numbers? Why do we need complicated ways to calcuate version numbers?

If I am correct, the version here is different from the version of software release to users.

Thanks.

ps: If you could go on to explain the the differences between the three methods, that would be great. Otherwise, I will ask for that in a new post.

Comment: Are you familiar with *semantic* versioning?

Comment: I looked at http://semver.org/ but am not sure what it is used for.

Comment: Incredibly oversimplified tl;dr: *breaking changes are only introduced in major version increments.*  Which means that you can generally upgrade libraries in minor version increments without worrying about breaking your program.

Comment: is "version" here version for source code during development?

Comment: Semantic versioning deals with production releases.

Comment: Isn't version for software releases to users created by incrementing the version numbers? Why do we need those three approaches?

Comment: Thought experiment: what if you wanted to pull down a specific production release from your Git repository?

Comment: I have never done that before, and don't know what will happen, why I would need to do that, and what I will look for.

Comment: @Tim How do you increment the version numbers? Where are the version numbers stored? What part should you increment? How much should they be incremented?

Comment: @8bittree isn't version number assigned to release, by simply incrementing the version numbers? Why do we need complicated ways to calcuate version numbers?

Comment: I think it's useful to have a way to correlate a version number with a specific "bookmark" in the source code repository.  Absent such a correlation, why bother with version numbers at all?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Do you mean that for each software release to user, we should associate it with a commit in the source code repository, which implements the release? Is the association done by assigning the same verison number to both the release and the source code commit?

Comment: As I understand it, that's where GitVersion comes in.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So I am correct that version number is used to associate software release and its source code commit. Why do we need complicated ways to calculate version numbers? Isn't it a simple thing to increment the version number, each time we create a new release? Which of major and minor number to increase depends on how drastic the change between the new release and the previous release, which is subject to the people who develop and release the software?

Comment: My best understanding of Git is that there really isn't a good story for tracking version numbers, especially across repositories.  Ergo, GitVersion.

Comment: @Tim "simply incrementing the version numbers" at best implies "add 1" to the version number**s** (plural, apparently?). And it doesn't actually say how to increment them (edit a text file? create a new tag? repaint the corporate headquarters building? is this done manually, or is there some automated scripting dealing with it?). It doesn't say how the version number is stored.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What is "tracking version numbers"? Does it mean to locate a commit when customer reports bug about a release ?

Comment: @Tim Do you ever use third party libraries in your code? Do you ever update them to take advantage of bug fixes or new features? (If not, why not?) If you do, how do you know if it's safe to update?

Comment: "Tracking" is being used as a verb here, not a noun.  But yes, that would be one possible use.

Comment: @8bittree  Is version number  stored in some file of software distribution of a release, and as tag on a source code commit in git repository?

Comment: @Tim It's something you as a developer have to decide.

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't a new version number created, by simply incrementing the version numbers? Why do we need complicated ways to calcuate version numbers?

Because we are programmers, and we don't like to perform repetitive steps manually.

Why would I manually edit a `version.txt` file when I can let the VCS compute it for me?