# What are "Version.txt/Version in build script" and "Build Server versioning"?

Tags: versioning

http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/why/ and https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion explain the advantage of   GitVersion over "Version.txt/Version in build script" and "Build Server versioning".

Before being able to understand that, I was wondering what the two other methods

- "Version.txt/Version in build script"
- "Build Server versioning"

are?

Thanks.

ps: How does "GitVersion"  work differently from them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is versioning (as in GitVersion) used for?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/358106/what-is-versioning-as-in-gitversion-used-for)

Answer (score 5):

**Version.txt** is referring to a file literally called "Version.txt" in which you store the version number. Changing the version number requires that a human edits the file manually.

**Version in build script** is nearly the same idea. It's just storing the version number as a variable in the build script (e.g. makefile, build.sh, build.gradle) instead of its own file. Again, it requires that a human manually modify a file to update the version number.

**Build server versioning** refers to making use of a build server to manage version numbers. Usually this means that part of the version number is a build number which is automatically incremented with every build. Storage of the version number might be done via a simple file, such as version.txt, or it may be something internal to the build server.

**GitVersion** appears somewhat similar to build server versioning, in that it can automatically update the version number, although it appears to have a bit more capability out of the box. It uses git tags and branches to calculate version numbers according to the [Semantic Versioning specification](http://semver.org/), though it appears it generally does not directly store the resulting version numbers (It looks like it can directly store them for Ruby gems and .NET assemblies). Instead it seems intended to be integrated with the build script or build server to actually make use of them. The main advantage here is the calculating new version numbers according to SemVer, and based off of git tags and branches. If you don't use SemVer, or you don't use version numbers in your tags and branches, then this won't be very useful to you.

---

In total, these different ideas can be more complementary than opposing. That is, you could have your build server run GitVersion, capture the output and write it to a file, then run the build script, which would pull the version from that file and write it into the actual built product.

In the context of GitVersion's claims of superiority, there's two major points:

1. The complaints about Version.txt and Version in build script are primarily about the need to manually update the version number for every build. For Build server versioning, it's that the auto updating version number isn't very smart.
2. GitVersion **strongly** encourages having version numbers in git tags and branches, which in turn makes it trivial to check out the source code corresponding to a specific version.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know how "GitVersion" work differently from them?

Comment: @Tim See my edits.